# Python Port Scanner says all ports are closed

Tags: python, sockets

I'm decently skilled in python programming and i'm trying to make a port scanner
without using any third party libraries. Below is the code I've written so far but the problem is that when i scan my laptop's IP address, it says that all the ports are closed. Is there something wrong with my code or are all the ports actually closed(if so, why?). Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

```
from socket import *

class scanner():
  def __init__(self, ip):
    self.ip = ip
    self.scan()

def scan(self):
    print("Starting scan on host: %s "%(self.ip))
    for i in range(0, 10000):
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            s.connect((ip, i))
            print('Port %d: OPEN' % (i))
            s.close()
        except:
            print('Port %d: CLOSED' % (i))
            s.close()


ip = input("Input IP address to scan: ")
scanner(ip)
```

Comment: Have you tried using nmap to see what ports are actually open?

Comment: use `except Exception as e:` and print `e` together with the message "Port %d: CLOSED"

Comment: Are you sure about this?...I tried your script it works fine, for example it says port 80 is OPEN !...

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i'm not familiar with nmap but i used comman prompt and it said a couple were listening

Comment: @mescalinum i just did that and they all say "[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond" but one of them says "[WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور yes, i'm positive, it lists all of them as closed including port 80

Comment: @KayceeOkoye Then I believe the issue is somewhere with your network setting...how are you connecting?...are you using proxy?...may be a firewall setting?...many reasons?

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the ip you're passing into the constructor:
instead of:

```
 s.connect((ip, i))
```

try:

```
 s.connect((self.ip, i))
```

Hope that helps!